# Which CA certificates to send, if you have multiple trust paths?

Tags: ssl, certificate-authority

I've come across this setting for the first time:

My server certificate is signed by INTERMEDIATE-CA1, which, in turn, is signed by  ROOT-CA1. ROOT-CA1 is in the trust store of my Browser/OS.

That being said, ROOT-CA1 is also signed by ROOT-CA2, which is also in the trust store of my Browser/OS.

This means, that on one trust path ROOT-CA1 ist the ROOT-CA (and therefore does not need to be sent by the server) but on the other trust path ROOT-CA1 has to be regarded as INTERMEDIATE-CA2 and should therefore be sent by the server.

Obviously, this cannot be fulfilled at the same time, as the chosen trust path depends on which ROOT-CAs the client has in its trust store.

So I'm basically asking two questions:

1. Which is the right way to handle this situation. My hunch is, that I
   as the server should also send the ROOT-CA1 certificate, but I have
   no RFC basis for that
2. Which are the relevant RFCs concerning the
   validation of TLS chains?

Comment: [RFC 5280 Section 6](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-6) deals with Basic Path Validation.  A great read when you have nothing else to do due to Covid-19 restrictions :-)

Answer (score 1):

TLS server SHALL NOT send root certificates at all. Plain and simple. You need to send leaf (TLS certificate) and non-root intermediate certificates if any. This solves all problems on your side.

BTW, certificate is signed by one CA only, there is only one `Issuer` field in certificate. And CA written there is an issuer. Another CA can cross-sign the certificate, but cross-signing for leaf certificates isn't supported, because you send certificate with particular issuer, so cross-signer won't match the chain.

Comment: "BTW, certificate is signed by one CA only, there is only one Issuer field in certificate."

Indeed, this seems to have been my error of thought. Thank you!

So basically, in my described situation, the way to go is to chose the path that is indicated by the `Issuer` field of the leaf certificate.